# OnTriggerEnter2D is being called multiple times

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, 2d

I'm new to Unity so sorry in advance if this is a basic question, I attached a variable that should add by 1 every time OnTriggerEnter2D is triggered. It however is not adding by 1 but adding constantly. Can please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is where I'm calling it

```
public class MonsterTarget : MonoBehaviour {
 public Resetter Resetting;
 public ScoreCount ScoreHit;
 public float targetHit = 0;


 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }

 public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
 {
     targetHit ++;
     Resetting.Reset();

 }
```

}

and this is where its going

```
public MonsterTarget monTarget;

 public Text scoreText;
 public Text highScoreText;

 public float scoreCount;
 public float highScoreCount;

 public bool scoreIncreasing;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
         {
         highScoreCount = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore");
     }
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     if (scoreIncreasing)
     {
         scoreCount += monTarget.targetHit;//RIGH HERE IS WHERE IM CALLING IT
     }

     if (scoreCount > highScoreCount)
     {
         highScoreCount = scoreCount;
         PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", highScoreCount);
     }

     scoreText.text = "Score: " + Mathf.Round(scoreCount);
     highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + Mathf.Round(highScoreCount);

 }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

"The scripting system can detect when collisions occur and initiate actions using the OnCollisionEnter function. However, you can also use the physics engine simply to detect when one collider enters the space of another without creating a collision. A collider configured as a Trigger (using the Is Trigger property) does not behave as a solid object and will simply allow other colliders to pass through. When a collider enters its space, a trigger will call the OnTriggerEnter function on the trigger object’s scripts."

From http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

I think it may be, because your object is inside the trigger space, so it is constantly being called.

**When a collider enters its space, a trigger will call the OnTriggerEnter function on the trigger object’s scripts.**

Which could mean that `targetHit ++;` keeps getting called while your object is passing through the collision space of your other object.

I'd suggest trying `OnCollisionEnter2D()` instead, as that way your object will collide but not pass through each other.